Azure API creating child under given parent
In my Azure project I have this Area: Exception/Child1.
If I now do this in C# with the Azure API:
Child1.Path the return is: "\Exception\Area\Child1"
My goal is to add a new Child below the Child1. For this I want to use this:
public async Task<WorkItemClassificationNode> CreateNewChild(WorkItemTrackingHttpClient client,       string projectName, WorkItemClassificationNode currentNode) {
    var newNode = new WorkItemClassificationNode()
    {
        Name = ChildChild,
        StructureType = TreeNodeStructureType.Area,
    };
    var newChild = client.WorkItemClassificationNodeAsync(newNode, projectName,    TreeStructureGroup.Areas, currentNode.Path)
}

My currentNode is Child1 and the error: 'VS402485: The Area/Iteration name is not recognized: Exception\Area\Child1'
Could anyone help me with this?
I tried to replace the currentNode.Path argument with "\Exception\Child1" but the same error occured.
Also I deleted the Path argument completely because it's not a required argument but then, ChildChild is a Child of Exception and not of Child1

Okay so the creation works now. The path you need to provide is this: "child1".
If I now want to create "Exception/Child1/ChildChild/ChildChildChild" my provided path is "Child1/ChildChild" and this works also.

I'm working with the Azure DevOps API to create nested area paths in a project. My code creates a first level child, then immediately tries to add a child under it, and so on, to create a multi-level structure.
The issue I'm facing: right after creating the first child, when I try to create the  second child area path, the API throws an error saying the path doesn’t exist. But if I re-run the code or wait a bit and try again, the path is there, and the child gets created just fine.
It seems like there’s a delay in Azure DevOps fully committing the newly created area paths.

Hi Paul, glad to know that you have solved the original question about the error: VS402485: The Area/Iteration name is not recognized: Exception\Area\Child1. You can share the solution by adding an answer. This may help other users who have the same question. :)  For your next question in the comment about the delay issue, I noticed that you have created a new question here, and it is solved now.

Which client libs do you use? Azure DevOps SDK contains CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.createorupdateclassificationnodeasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet
Example:
newNode = CreateArea(TeamProjectName, @"Database"); //Add area Database
newNode = CreateArea(TeamProjectName, @"Operational", @"Database"); //Add area Database\Operational

static WorkItemClassificationNode CreateArea(string TeamProjectName, string AreaName, string ParentAreaPath = null)
{
    WorkItemClassificationNode newArea = new WorkItemClassificationNode();
    newArea.Name = AreaName;

    return WitClient.CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync(newArea, TeamProjectName, TreeStructureGroup.Areas, ParentAreaPath).Result;
}

